# Looking for a Discworld quote involving Rincewind running away and not looking behind

Tags: episode-identification, quotes, discworld

Rincewind is running away (obviously) and the quote goes along these lines:

> A less experienced coward might take a moment to look over their shoulder, but Rincewind knew better. Nothing he saw could make him run any faster than he was already and he knew that was just the moment a rock would be most likely to appear underfoot.

It made me laugh for months but I can't find it for love nor money.

Comment: A related quote, as paraphrased by https://discworld.fandom.com/wiki/Rincewind, is that when running, "to" is never important, what matters is "from".  From the book Eric: *Come on. Let's run away."* / *"Where to?"* / *Rincewind sighed. He'd tried to make his basic philosophy clear time and again, and
people never got the message.* / *"Don't you worry about to," he said. "In my experience that always takes care of itself.
The important word is away.”* https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/9078351-come-on-let-s-run-away-where-to-rincewind-sighed-he-d  A similar discussion with Nijel also exists.

Comment: Unrelated but thematically similar "What's behind me is not important" --Raul Julia, The Gumball Rally

Answer (score 32, accepted):

From *Interesting Times*:

> A less practised runner would have risked a glance behind, but Rincewind instinctively knew all about wind drag and the tendency for inconvenient rocks to position themselves under the unwary foot. Besides, why look behind? He was already running as fast as he could. Nothing he could see would make him run any faster.

Comment: Any idea where in the book? Obviously the chapter number is not going to help :)

Comment: @Jontia it's after he parts ways with the Silver Horde after arriving in the empire, and before he meets Pretty Butterfly - page 104 of 352 in my Corgi paperback